# ModuleNotFoundError with Django, not recognizing app's name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting the same exception whenever I try to run a Django command (`makemigrations`, `migrate`, `shell`, `runserver`). I looked at other posts but nothing has helped. I changed around the naming of the app but that didn't work either. The exception traceback is:

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f3c3ff9dc80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/projects/myproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr/projects/myproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/usr/projects/myproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/usr/projects/myproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/usr/projects/myproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr/projects/myproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/usr/projects/myproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/usr/projects/myproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/usr/projects/myproject/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'
```

My `apps.py` is:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'
    verbose_name = 'Project API'
```

and in my `__init__.py` for the main project I have:

```
default_app_config = 'api.apps.ApiConfig'
```

and my `INSTALLED_APPS` is:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'api',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'rest_framework',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
]
```

I'm using version 2.1.3 for Django if that makes a difference. From what I can tell, the issue involves `INSTALLED_APPS` as whenever I changed that the module that can't be found changes to whatever I added.

Structure:

```
-myproject
  -api
    django app files
  -settings.py
  -init
  -urls
  -wsgi.py
```

Comment: What's the name of the directory that contains your `settings.py` file?

Comment: Also, why do you have both `'api'` and `'api.apps.ApiConfig'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: You don't need `api` and `api.apps.ApiConfig` If you've got a specific config, just use that and not the base name.

Comment: I added both just to test if it would change anything, but it didn't work.

Comment: The structure of my project is edited in the question

Comment: It doesn't matter if I change what is in `INSTALLED_APPS` to `api` or `api.apps.ApiConfig`, it doesn't recognize the name `api`.

Comment: Your `api/` directory, containing your app, is inside your project directory? Beside `settings.py`? It shouldn't be. Move it up one directory so it's beside your project directory and get rid of one of the `INSTALLED_APPS` entries. If that works I'll add a proper answer.

Comment: Ahhh that was it. Thank you so much @Chris!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your app directory is inside your project directory. It actually needs to be one directory up, *beside* your project directory.

Move it from `myproject/api/` to `api/`, remove one of the entries from `INSTALLED_APPS`, and it should work.